# Ruby on Rails: How to automatically disable my out of stock products link, when stock == 0 on my product show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an option on my products show page, that lets you choose the size that you would want your product in. When the product reaches stock == 0, it automatically says the Size name and "- sin stock (without available stock). **The problem is that even if it displays without stock, you are still able to put the product with unavailable stock in the cart.**

I would like to know if there is a ruby code or a way to see all the sizes and choose from them but have the ones without stock "xs - sin stock" disabled when clicked on.

What would be the best way to do this?

**Size.rb file**

```
class Size < ApplicationRecord

  def self.options_for product_id
    all.collect {|s| [display_format(s, product_id), s.id] }
  end

  private
  def self.display_format size, product_id
    name  = '%-3.3s' % size.name
    stock = Stock.by_size(product_id, size.id)
      if stock == 0
       **"#{name} - Sin Stock"**
    else
      "#{name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Part in Product show page where size is selected:

```
     <%= label :size_id, 'Seleciona tu talle' %>
      <%= form_tag product_items_path(product_id: @product.id) do %>
      <%= select_tag :size_id,
         options_for_select(
           sizes_for(@product.id)),
         prompt: "Seleciona tu talle"
         %>
```

Comment: Are you having a single products page with options on it, ie t-shirt page with small/medium/large that you can add to your cart, or would that be 3 separate pages? If its a single page, can you show the view code where you are making the selection?

Comment: add a logic where you add the product to the cart, check the product is available then add to kart else pop error.

Comment: I added an example to show how you would use this in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify other html attributes after the first two elements in the array. This will disable the option if you have less than 1 available.

```rb
class Size < ApplicationRecord

    def self.options_for product_id
        all.collect do |size|
            stock = Stock.by_size(product_id, size.id)
            is_disabled = stock < 1
            [display_format(size, stock), size.id, disabled: is_disabled]
        end
    end

    private
    def self.display_format size, stock
        name = '%-3.3s' % size.name

        if stock == 0
            "#{name} - Sin Stock"
        else
            name
        end
    end
end
```

And using this in you view:

```rb
<%= form_tag product_items_path(product_id: @product.id) do %>
    <%= label_tag :size_id, 'Seleciona tu talle' %>
    <%= select_tag :size_id, 
        options_for_select(Size.options_for(@product.id), @product.size_id),
        prompt: "Seleciona tu talle" %>
<% end %>
```

You would still want to check the stock level in the checkout process since I could manually modify the form information to submit bad data.

Comment: Oops sorry, I added the selection part here instead of on my post. Will try this now. Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am trying the disabled code in many ways now to figure it out. 

When I add the code to my size.rb file I get this error:

undefined local variable or method `size' for #<Class:0x00007ff78b5b0da8>

coming from: stock = Stock.by_size(product_id, size.id)

Comment: Terribly sorry about that, I typo’d the variable name. It’s updated